# SQL Server row change to column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data in a SQL Server table with the following structure:

```
TradeDateTime          Strike CallOI
2023-08.02 15.01.00    19500  31015
2023-08.02 15.01.00    19550  2606
2023-08.02 15.01.00    19600  18062
2023-08.02 15.01.00    19650  2553
```

I want to change as like this

```
TradeDateTime        19500   19550  19600   19650
2023-08.02 15.01.00  31015   2606   18062   2553
```

I want change row to column using SQL query. Please help me.

[image]

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Be great to see what you have tried.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931607/convert-rows-to-columns-using-pivot-in-sql-server

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for dynamic T-SQL PIVOT. The idea is simple - build the PIVOT columns using DISTINCT over the [Strike] column values.

```
CREATE TABLE #DataSource
(
    [TradeDateTime] VARCHAR(32)
   ,[Strike] INT
   ,[CallOI] INT
);

INSERT INTO #DataSource ([TradeDateTime], [Strike], [CallOI])
VALUES ('2023-08.02 15.01.00', 19500, 31015)
      ,('2023-08.02 15.01.00', 19550, 2606)
      ,('2023-08.02 15.01.00', 19600, 18062)
      ,('2023-08.02 15.01.00', 19650, 2553);

DECLARE @DynamicTSQLStatement NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @DynamicPIVOTColumns NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @DynamicPIVOTColumns = STUFF
                          (
                                (
                                SELECT ',[' + CAST([Strike] AS VARCHAR(12)) + ']'
                                FROM #DataSource
                                GROUP BY [Strike]
                                ORDER BY [Strike]
                                FOR XML PATH('') ,TYPE
                                ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
                                ,1
                                ,1
                                ,''
                          );

SET @DynamicTSQLStatement = N'
SELECT *
FROM #DataSource
PIVOT
(
    MAX([CallOI]) FOR [Strike] IN (' + @DynamicPIVOTColumns + ')
) PVT';

EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicTSQLStatement;

DROP TABLE #DataSource;
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Brother for your help, It is very good, Excellent.